# Assign color to gridlines automatically

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of equations and I plotted them as follows. I want to plot gridlines for each equation accordingly and assign the same color to the gridline in the same order as the set of the functions. How should I do this?

```
y = {x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x};
gridlines = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Plot[Evaluate@Table[y[[i]], {i, 1, 4}], {x, 0, 4}, 
 GridLines -> {gridlines, None}]
```

Comment: Is this a minimal example of what you seek?  Do we really need to know all the specifics of these equations?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Changed it.

Comment: So you want the first gridline Blue, then Yellow etc?

Comment: @Feyre MMA gives colors to function y automatically and I want the same color to the corresponding gridlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y = {x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x};
gridlines = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Define the gridline function, works for up to 15 functions in y.

```
gl = Transpose[{gridlines, 
    Table[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i]], {i, Length[gridlines]}]}];
```

Plot

```
Plot[y, {x, 0, 4}, 
 GridLines -> {gl, None}]
```

[image]